# Can't bind ImageView in adapter class

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I've got problem with binding ImageView in my adapter. How I should do it properly?

Here's the code:

```
Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (view != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.weather_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    Weather model = getItem(position);
    holder.weatherIcon.setImageResource(utils.setWeatherIcon(model.getForecastID(), weatherIcon)); <- on the weatherIcon, I've got the "Cannot resolve symbol "weatherIcon"

static class ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.hourly_temperature)
    TextView temperature;
    @BindView(R.id.hourly_airPressure)
    TextView airPressure;
    @BindView(R.id.hourly_airHumidity)
    TextView airHumidity;
    @BindView(R.id.hourly_windSpeed)
    TextView windSpeed;
    @BindView(R.id.hourly_time)
    TextView hour;

    @BindView(R.id.hourly_weatherIcon)
    ImageView weatherIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

Before I used ButterKnife, I was declaring ImageView like that:

```
    ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.someID);
    utils.setWeatherIcon(model.getIconID(), iv);
```

and everything was runing just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@BindView(R.id.hourly_weatherIcon) ImageView weatherIcon;
```

use

```
@Bind(R.id.hourly_weatherIcon) ImageView weatherIcon;
```